# trying to show the email and password Written in email and password inputs issue

Tags: php

I´m trying to show in a `'<pre></pre>'` the values that are passed in the form. 
But Its not working and give my some errors:

-> *Notice: Undefined index: email in*

-> *Notice: Undefined index: pass*

-> *Notice: Undefined index: remember*

I already tried put isset like this:

```
$f['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['email']));
$f['pass'] = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['pass']));
$f['save'] = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['remember']));
```

And this way above I dont have erros but the data that I write in the form inputs dont show in my

```
echo '<pre class="debug">';
print_r($f);
echo '</pre>';
```

Can you see something that Im doing wrong?

My code:

```
 <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sendLogin']))
            {
                $f['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
                $f['pass'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
                $f['save'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['remember']);

                echo '<pre class="debug">';
                print_r($f);
                echo '</pre>';
            }

        ?>


    <?php
        if(!isset($_GET['remember']))
        {
        ?>
        <form name="login" action="" method="post">
            <label>
                <span>Email:</span>
                <input type="text" class="radius" name="<?php if($f['email']) echo $f['email']; ?>" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Password:</span>
                <input type="password" class="radius" name="<?php if($f['pass']) echo $f['pass']; ?>" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sendLogin" class="btn" />

            <div class="remember">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" 
            <?php if(isset($f['save'])) echo 'checked="checked"' ?> 
/>
```

Comment: what this line is for name="<?php if($f['email']) echo $f['email']; ?>" ?? just add the name attributes to your input elements as email,pass etc so that on POST you can get them using the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have made mistake with name attribute. You should have static name="email" and name="pass" in the inputs. While your current name attribute change to value:

```
<input type="text" class="radius" name="email" value="<?php if($f['email']) echo $f['email']; ?>" />
<input type="password" class="radius" name="pass" value="<?php if($f['pass']) echo $f['pass']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs must have the name attribute in order to be accessible in the PHP

```
<form name="login" action="" method="post">
            <label>
                <span>Email:</span>
                <input type="text" class="radius" value="<?php if($f['email']) echo $f['email']; ?>" name="email" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Password:</span>
                <input type="password" class="radius" value="<?php if($f['pass']) echo $f['pass']; ?>" name="password" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sendLogin" class="btn" />

            <div class="remember">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" 
            <?php if(isset($f['save'])) echo 'checked="checked"' ?> 
/>
```

Comment: so ur answer has 2 names in the input !!

Answer (score 0):

In `<input type="text">` as well as in `<input type="password">` block, provide a meaningful value for the name attribute.
Here in your code provide name="email" and for the next one name="pass".
Also to display the email/pass values after the form submission, give it in value attribute.
Right now you wrongly given inside the name attribute.

value=`"<?php if($f['email']) echo $f['email']; ?>"` and

value=`"<?php if($f['pass']) echo $f['pass']; ?>"`